# SQL - only show latest record (order by desc) from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case-when

I am using the following codes as a query to return data from our sql server (for ERP system) in Excel.

I am trying to select only the top 1 record from the `Job.Job` (Job table), based on sorting by `desc`. However, I can't get it to work with either the `select top` or `limit` function. I also tried the `case when else` function in `where`, but couldn't wrap my head around.

I will be great if you can shed some light on how to modify the following code to do that.

[image]
**** to only return the first row of each `Material` ****

```
SELECT
  SO_Detail.Status,
  SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
  SO_Detail.SO_Line,
  SO_Detail.Material,
  SO_Detail.Rev,
  SO_Header.Customer_PO,
  SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
  Coalesce(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty, 0),
  SO_Detail.Promised_Date,
  SO_Detail.Note_Text,
  Material.Description,
  Job.Status AS Status1,
  Job.Job 

FROM
  SO_Detail
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Header ON SO_Detail.Sales_Order = SO_Header.Sales_Order
  INNER JOIN Material ON Material.Material = SO_Detail.Material
  INNER JOIN Job ON SO_Detail.Material = Job.Part_Number

WHERE
  SO_Detail.Status = 'open'

ORDER BY
  SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
  SO_Detail.SO_Line,
  Job.Job desc
```

Comment: What about Max(Job.Job) function?

Comment: I suggest that you add a tag for the SQL database software that you are using (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) That may help you to get more applicable answers to your question.

Comment: Try "limit 1" at the very end of the statement.

Comment: I have tried "limit 1" at the end of the statement (after job.job desc), however, I got an error message says "incorrect syntax near "limit"

Comment: Is that picture a result of your query? Except you only want the top 1 result? i.e. latest Job #?

Comment: I noticed you changed you have updated your question to properly reflect what you need. Go ahead and have a look at my update @JackLuo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
   ( SELECT
      SO_Detail.Status,
      SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
      SO_Detail.SO_Line,
      SO_Detail.Material,
      SO_Detail.Rev,
      SO_Header.Customer_PO,
      SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
      Coalesce(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty, 0) Column1,
      SO_Detail.Promised_Date,
      SO_Detail.Note_Text,
      Material.Description,
      Job.Status AS Status1,
      Job.Job, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SO_Detail.Material ORDER BY Job.Job desc) AS RN
    FROM
      SO_Detail
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Header ON SO_Detail.Sales_Order = SO_Header.Sales_Order
      INNER JOIN Material ON Material.Material = SO_Detail.Material
      INNER JOIN Job ON SO_Detail.Material = Job.Part_Number
    WHERE
      SO_Detail.Status = 'open'
) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY
  Sales_Order,
  SO_Line
```

Answer (score 1):

Without enough information, I would try using a `row_number` function or a `case` statement in your `order by`:

Using a `row_number` function and a derived table:

```
select *
from
(SELECT
  SO_Detail.Status,
  SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
  SO_Detail.SO_Line,
  SO_Detail.Material,
  SO_Detail.Rev,
  SO_Header.Customer_PO,
  SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
  Coalesce(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty, 0),
  SO_Detail.Promised_Date,
  SO_Detail.Note_Text,
  Material.Description,
  Job.Status AS Status1,
  Job.Job,
  row_number() over (partition by job.job order by job.job desc) rn

FROM
  SO_Detail
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Header ON SO_Detail.Sales_Order = SO_Header.Sales_Order
  INNER JOIN Material ON Material.Material = SO_Detail.Material
  INNER JOIN Job ON SO_Detail.Material = Job.Part_Number

WHERE
  SO_Detail.Status = 'open') t

where t.rn = 1
```

Using a `case` statement in your `order by` and a `top 1`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  SO_Detail.Status,
  SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
  SO_Detail.SO_Line,
  SO_Detail.Material,
  SO_Detail.Rev,
  SO_Header.Customer_PO,
  SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
  Coalesce(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty, 0),
  SO_Detail.Promised_Date,
  SO_Detail.Note_Text,
  Material.Description,
  Job.Status AS Status1,
  Job.Job 

FROM
  SO_Detail
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Header ON SO_Detail.Sales_Order = SO_Header.Sales_Order
  INNER JOIN Material ON Material.Material = SO_Detail.Material
  INNER JOIN Job ON SO_Detail.Material = Job.Part_Number

WHERE
  SO_Detail.Status = 'open'

ORDER BY
  SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
  SO_Detail.SO_Line,
  Job.Job desc,
  case when job.status = 'Complete' then 1 else 2 end
```

If neither works please provide more details, like sample data and tables. Please note that you have a `SQL-Server` tag, and `limit` is a MySQL syntax.

**Update**:

I came back and saw that you have updated your question. This will return the latest result for EACH material:

```
select *
from
(SELECT
  SO_Detail.Status,
  SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
  SO_Detail.SO_Line,
  SO_Detail.Material,
  SO_Detail.Rev,
  SO_Header.Customer_PO,
  SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
  Coalesce(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty, 0),
  SO_Detail.Promised_Date,
  SO_Detail.Note_Text,
  Material.Description,
  Job.Status AS Status1,
  Job.Job ,
  row_number() over(partition by Material.Description order by Job.Job desc) rn

FROM
  SO_Detail
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Header ON SO_Detail.Sales_Order = SO_Header.Sales_Order
  INNER JOIN Material ON Material.Material = SO_Detail.Material
  INNER JOIN Job ON SO_Detail.Material = Job.Part_Number

WHERE
  SO_Detail.Status = 'open') t --name of derived query

where t.rn = 1
-- you can then add an order statement if you need. Keep in note 
-- I named the derived query t. So if you need to order by it'll need to be t.column
```

In the future if you comment and let answerer's know you've updated or what work or didn't you'll likely get your question answered. Else it'll just sit in queue and disappear into internet space.

Comment: thank you for your advice! I'll try to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

For select desc top 1 row in Job table, u can write a lil select sentence

```
SELECT 
SO_Detail.Status, 
SO_Detail.Sales_Order, 
SO_Detail.SO_Line,
SO_Detail.Material,
SO_Detail.Rev,
SO_Header.Customer_PO,
SO_Detail.Order_Qty,
Coalesce(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty, 0),
SO_Detail.Promised_Date,
SO_Detail.Note_Text,
Material.Description,
Job.Status AS Status1,
Job.Job 
FROM
SO_Detail
LEFT OUTER JOIN Material_Location ON SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Header ON SO_Detail.Sales_Order = SO_Header.Sales_Order
INNER JOIN Material ON Material.Material = SO_Detail.Material
INNER JOIN (Select top 1 * from Job order by Job.Job desc) as TempJob ON     SO_Detail.Material = TempJob.Part_Number
WHERE
SO_Detail.Status = 'open'
ORDER BY
SO_Detail.Sales_Order,
SO_Detail.SO_Line,
JobTemp.Job desc
```